# Message Framework - Remove duplicate message

Tags: django, django-messages

I have the following code:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

There are situations when the same message is repeated multiple times. How can I make the messages to be unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default storage by creating your own class and setting it in your settings file.

```
class MyMessageStorage(BaseStorage):  
    # you could override FallbackStorage, CookieStorage or SessionStorage instead
    self._logged_messages = set()

       def add(self, level, message, extra_tags=''):
           if message in self._logged_messages:
               return
           return super().add(level, message, extra_tags)
```

And in settings.py

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'path.to.MyMessageStorage'
```